# Need assistance fixing maximum update depth exceeded issue

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to write a hacky fix to ScrollableTabView since it isn't playing nice with the function that triggers when there's a tab switch. When I replace the setState with console.log I see that it only triggers once with every tab switch so it's not looping infinitely like the error is complaining.

Parent container

```
  state = {
    headerName: 'Loading',
  }
  setHeader = (header) => {
    this.setState({'headerName': header})
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <ScrollableTabView
        renderTabBar={() => <BottomTabBar setHeader={this.setHeader} headerNames={['A','B','C']} />}
      >
    )
  }
```

BottomTabBar

```
  render() {
    this.props.setHeader(this.props.headerNames[this.props.activeTab])
    ...
  }
```